# Consuming Spring REST API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, rest

I wrote simple Spring REST webapp. Now I want to consume my API with some client. I decided to write jQuery client.

I've found in internet some examples so I've tried something like this:

**.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Hello jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="user-id">User id is </p>
        <p class="user-email">His email: </p>
        <p class="user-username">He is known as: </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1",
        dataType: "json"
        }).then(function(data) {
            $('.user-id').append(data.userId);
            $('.user-email').append(data.email);
            $('.user-username').append(data.username);
        });
});
```

**"http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1"** returns:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "email": "email2@at.pl",
  "password": "haslo123",
  "username": "witek",
  "birthday": "1992-07-12",
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1"
    },
    {
      "rel": "shopping-lists",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1/shopping-lists"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I open html through Chrome it doesnt get any data. What am i doing wrong?

Edit: With `url:/api/v1/users/1"` Chrome dev console shouts: `jquery.min.js:6 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/api/v1/users/1. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Having `url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1"` returns erorr `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`.

**Temporary solution:**
Found something. Launching my page at Chrome started this way: `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` makes my page working. But I dont think this solution.

Comment: You might want to read about CORS.

Comment: Is it failing for you locally or is your rest api on a remote host?

Comment: Rest API is locally.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see in your chrome developer console (right click inspect) and verify the networks tab for errors, if any. Basically, check what is the actual url and network call that is made.

Comment: Doesn't help, still `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error.

Comment: Since you are just trying this to learn, I would suggest that you install the chrome CORS plugin https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN7Ou9gYfUAhUr1oMKHUxSA1IQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fallow-control-allow-origi%2Fnlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNHSUFqc6ylxfxfbWzmmFJ6L5QUvyg&sig2=vwb4F5soMXsVnHxoyYdFxw

Comment: Yup, this helps ;)

Comment: Helped, but using it, I cant use my Facebook chat and some other pages properly :/

Comment: How do you access the html file ? I think the issue is that html file is not being served by origin: localhost:8080 and that is causing the issue. My guess is - if you move the html file to your springboot root directory and try accessing it there, then both belong to the same origin

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the json saved in test.json (and the ajax call pointing to that) and it is working for me as-is.